# How to make a horizontal line without using <hr> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags, visual-web-developer-2010

How can I draw a thin horizontal line without using the `<hr>` tag ?

I tried this:

```css
.horizontal-line{
  border-top: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9E9E9E;
}
```

Although it works, I want this line to be thinner. I tried to reduce 1px to 0.5px, but it didn't work.

Comment: `0.5px` and `0.25px` work just fine in my browser.

Comment: also if you want the line to be thinner, just use border-top or border-bottom, not both (if you're using as a replacement to `<hr>`

Comment: Don't use border? Use `background-color: #9E9E9E; height: 0.5px;`?

Comment: It can depend on your browser and/or device as to how part CSS pixels render on screens - particularly on those where several screen pixels make up one CSS pixel. And you may find the resulting width depends on zoom level.

Comment: Short hand : `<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray" ></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it but there is not much difference.

```css
.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 0.2px solid red;
}

hr {
  border-top: 0.2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  content
</div>
<span class='line'></span>
<div>
  content
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  content
</div>
```

Comment: @VartikaMalguri You could [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it is working nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Per [this](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/trick-get-a-horizontal-line-without-using/) css-tricks discussion, you could give this a go:

```css
.class-name:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #9E9E9E;
}
```

```html
<div class="class-name"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this. we cant make the size of the borders less than 1px in CSS so  I have tried this way. Feel free to change the opacity.

```
.horizental-line{
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background-color: rgb(122, 121, 121);
opacity: 0.5;
```

}